# implement login screen before swrevealcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I've just started learning IOS development, I've successfully implemented the SWRevealViewController by following a given tutorial online all is working as expected.

I've then decided to add a login screen, which would be the first page the user see's when the application is run.  The steps I took are a follows:

1. Dropped a UIViewController onto the story board
2. Set this as my 'is initial view controller'
3. Added a button to this new view and created a seque for testing purposes

But when I click this button it does nothing, so after searching the web and trying to figure this one by my self unfortunately I've been unsuccessful due to my lack of knowledge on this, would someone be kind enough to give me some pointers on what I need to change if anything, or what sections need to me modified to make this flow work as expected?

Below is a screen grab of my current story board.

[image]

**Update**

After adding the relevant code the app delegate file I still receieve this error message:

[image]

Comment: embed the loginviewcontroller with navigationcontroller and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for your response, I've just tried this however the result is the same.

Comment: can you send your project i will fix this

Comment: Can you explain how you made the segue from the button to the viewcontroller? It looks like the segues are configured incorrectly.

Comment: change your custom segue from login to SWL as Modal surely works

Comment: @James Certainly, I added the button then made sure the button was selected, held down control / left click of mouse then dragged to the given controller and selected reveal view controller push controller

Comment: @CodeRatchet - i am waiting for your response

Comment: make Login Screen as InitialViewController

Comment: @Rushi Already done that as mentioned in step 2 of my question.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik How can I send you my project?

Comment: @CodeRatchet - how much size of that your project , zip and send to my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik not very big, the project is on its way to you.

Comment: @CodeRatchet - ok only its take to complete for 15 minutes

Comment: @CodeRatchet - task is over check your inbox\

Comment: I it throwing me `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error on click of button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step-1**

embed your login VC to NavigationController.

**Step-2**

on your login button action set the segue type as `Modal` and call as

```
 @IBAction func btnLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openSWL", sender: self)
  }
```

**For flow understand purpose**

[image]

For sample Project you can [download here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/75l7ik)

Comment: Yes it is thanks, one question though when the user clicks logout how would I get them to navigate back to the login screen?

Comment: Hello,I want to pass data from view controller to reveal view controller, when override `prepareForSegue` and pass string it is giving me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` Please help on how to pass data..

Comment: Thank you Thank you, you solved my problem too, I was searching all over the internet for 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The Storyboard arrangement looks good. I have used `SWRevealController` like below:

After you login (performing login service or some login process) write below code.
This code will change current rootViewController (In your case it is `LoginViewController`) to `SWRevealController`. So that it will work. And when ever you do logout change rootViewController to `LoginViewController`.

```
SWRevealViewController *controller = (SWRevealViewController *)[self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RevealViewController"];
[self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

Do not forget to assign StoryboardID = "RevealViewController" in Storyboard for `SWRevealViewController`.

**Swift Code:**

Add below function to your `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
func changeRootViewControllerToSWRevealViewController () {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealViewController")
    if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = controller
    }
}
```

// Call above function in your login button action method like below:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.changeRootViewControllerToSWRevealViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using swift code, I've pasted what you have provided in my button function and its highlighted an error which reads: Consecutive statements on a line but be seperated with ;

I've gone through and tried setting the ; where I feel it should go however I'm unable to remove this error.  Can you please advise?

Comment: just tried the swift code, i'm now getting the error 'LoginViewController does not have a member names window'

Comment: @CodeRatchet: Sorry I forgot to mention that you need to write this code in `AppDelegate`

Comment: after pasting the func changeRootViewcontrollerToSwRevealViewcontroller in app delete file it highlights red with the following error message:  Cannot assign a value 'AnyObject!' to a value of type 'UIViewController'

Comment: @CodeRatchet: I guess you are using older Swift version. try replacing this line in function `let controller : UIViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealViewController")
`

Comment: changed the function to what you supplied, the error now reads : 'AnyObject!" is not convertible to UIViewController 

on the let controller line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112352/discussion-between-kampai-and-coderatchet).