# iOS Swift - SWRevealViewController can't be accessed after google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

After successfully sign in via google, I can't seem to access the `SWRevealViewController`. The icon and animation is there but clicking it doesn't open up the menu. I'm not sure if I have to go to `ViewController` (code in the image) and push to reveal the `SWRevealViewController` or not. I'm kinda new to `swift`. Please help !

[image: App Delegate GIDSigin Function]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Please copy and paste the actual code into your question (and make sure it is properly formatted).

Comment: can you show your storyboard screens, no need of multiple codes

Comment: see this you get idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295895/implement-login-screen-before-swrevealcontroller/37314944#37314944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is after you SignIn, you changed the window's rootViewController. And I don't see you instantiating SWRevealController anywhere.There should be SWRevealController as a window's rootView Controller.

Comment: thanks. Although it's late but i think i got it working